# Not logged in at Pluralsight

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, login, pluralsight-iq

I was able to get a Pluralsight assignment before and I was successfully logged in with my Stack Overflow linked account. But now it doesn't work anymore.

Clicking "Get your Skill IQ" on Stack Overflow Jobs leads to [`https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/integration/assessment?s=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/integration/assessment?s=1), which forwards to `https://www.pluralsight.com/partners/stack-overflow/iq?aid=[ID]&promo=&oid=[ID]&utm_source=&utm_medium=partner_partner_web_referral&utm_campaign=&utm_content=&utm_term=`.
I only censored the "aid" and "oid" variables, because I don't know what they are. The other variables are actually empty and the `&` in the link follows directly after the `=` of the previous variable. I don't know if that's intended.

The result is the same as just opening [`pluralsight.com/partners/stack-overflow`](https://www.pluralsight.com/partners/stack-overflow/iq).

Comment: Possibly related to [support for OpenID ending](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-25-2018)?

Comment: @SOLO no, this one looks like something very specific to Jobs.

Comment: @SOLO I'm not using OpenID, if that's the question. Shadow Wizard, thanks for migration.

Comment: Alright then. I made a big leap from the error message I got back when I poked at it ("stackoverflow.com is not a supported identity provider").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are redirected to Pluralsight, you need to log in there and find the result you want to share with your developer story.

Once you do, open it and you should use the Stack Overflow icon to share it back.

[image]

Once you click it, you should be redirected to your dev story where you can confirm that you want it there.

Comment: A password reset worked. But I don't remember ever creating an account there and there was also no password in my password database.

Comment: glad it worked :) I remember not having a password when I first attempted to log in and had to go the same route as you did.

Comment: Is that a bug or just changed behaviour?

Comment: that's by design on Pluralsight's end